# Istio - URI Rewrite with URI Regex Match

Tags: istio

So relatively new to Istio and have a question regarding Istio. Say that I want to rewrite a URI based on a path, but use part of that original uri in the rewrite, is that something I could do with Regex? I'm imagining something like this

```
http:
  - match:
    - uri:
       regex: ^/(.*\s*)?(canary)(.*)?$
    rewrite:
      prefix: "/$1"
```

Where $1 would be a matching group on the uri regex. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Hi @DominicEU, I'm trying to do a very similar write. Can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only those rule, which contain [StringMatch](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#StringMatch) type of values can work with  regex. For example [HTTPMatchRequest](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest).

Unfortunately **NOT** [HTTPRewrite](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite), which takes only `strings` as a value